# jqPlot not rendering on page load but works propely when an item from select list is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dateFormat;
        var ajaxDataRenderer = function () {
            var chartDataArr = [];
            var id = $("#industryList option:selected").val();
            var url = window.baseUrl + "Widget/GlobalThreatConChartData/" + id;
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    chartDataArr = JSON.parse("[" + data.ChartData + "]");
                    dateFormat = data.DateFormat;
                }
            });
            return chartDataArr;
        };

        var threatChart = function () {
            var chartData = ajaxDataRenderer();

            if ($.isArray(chartData) && chartData[0].length > 0) {
                $.jqplot('threatConChart', chartData, {
                    animate: true,
                    animateReplot: true,
                    series: [{
                        rendererOptions: {
                            animation: {
                                speed: 2000
                            }
                        }
                    }],
                    legend: { show: false },
                    axes: {
                        xaxis: {
                            numberTicks: 7,
                            tickOptions: {
                                showGridline: false,
                                angle: -45,
                                formatString: dateFormat,
                                fontFamily: 'HP Simplified',
                                fontSize: '8pt',
                                textColor: '#000000'
                            },
                            renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                            tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
                        },
                        yaxis: {
                            min: 1,
                            max: 5,
                            numberTicks: 3,
                            tickOptions: {
                                formatString: '%d',
                                fontFamily: 'HP Simplified',
                                fontSize: '8pt'
                            },
                            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
                        }
                    },
                    grid: {
                        drawGridLines: true,
                        background: '#ffffff',
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        shadow: false,
                    },
                    seriesDefaults: {
                        show: true,
                        xaxis: 'xaxis',
                        yaxis: 'yaxis',
                        color: '#0096d6',
                        lineWidth: 1.5,
                        showLine: true,
                        showMarker: false,
                        renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer,
                        shadow: false
                    },
                    highlighter: {
                        show: false
                    },
                    cursor: {
                        show: true,
                        tooltipLocation: 'sw',
                        followMouse: true
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $("#threatConChart").append("<br/><br/><div class='center'>No data available to plot chart.</div>");
            }
        };

        //Call threat chart on select change
        $("#industryList").change(function () {
            $('#loader').show();
            $('#threatConChart').empty();
            threatChart();
            threatGauge();
        });

        //Call for the first time with first value
        threatChart();
    });

</script>
<div id="threatConChart" class="right-widget-content chart-size"></div>
```

The required JS files are called from the master page. This is a partial view loaded through ajax.

The chart is not rendered when the page is loaded first. There is a select list in the page. While I select an item from the list, the chart renders appropriately.

I have noticed that it adds the class 'jqplot-target' in the div. It means it  goes into jquery.jplot.js file.

Also the data is properly received. I have checked that.

Please suggest what I am possibly missing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure than jqplot file is fully loaded before the call of `$(document).ready(function(){`.

Try to replace it by `$(window).load(function(){`

Comment: It is not working. Further more the page having jqPlot is retrieved via ajax, so I think $(window).load(function(){ would not be valid in this case. As the window is not getting loaded at this moment.